# std::map on gcc 3.2.3 Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-20

Tags: c++, gcc, redhat

I am an ATE engineer in a semiconductor company and I need to develop as well as maintain test programs. Recently I would like to add a config file parsing function in the ATE platform. However, the standard test platform is not up-to-date (I am not sure whether this caused the problem).

I checked some resources and found several candidates: getpot(http://getpot.sourceforge.net/), inih(https://github.com/benhoyt/inih). With both, I could use directly compile and run on my windows 7 with gcc 4.8.1. However I would have to use it on my ATE Red Hat 3.2.3. I can not change the platform (like update the gcc version, install new packages), but I could include all necessary codes as raw files.

Here is what I have tried with inih:

1: I copied the codes to shared folder (between host windows and virtual redhat machine). On windows, I make it to compile and run correctly. However, on red hat it shows error as below [image]. Here is the part which showed error:

```
string INIReader::Get(string section, string name, string default_value) const
{
    string key = MakeKey(section, name);
    return _values.count(key) ? _values.at(key) : default_value;
}
```

I just tried to modify it to implement std::map::at as below:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
T2 mapAt(std::map<T1, T2, T3, T4>& m, const T1& key)
{
    typeof(m.begin()) mit = m.find(key);
    if (mit == m.end() || mit->first != key)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("map::at");
    }
    return mit->second;
}

string INIReader::Get(string section, string name, string default_value) const
{
    string key = MakeKey(section, name);
    return _values.count(key) ? mapAt(_values, key) : default_value;
}
```

and still it generates error as below:

[image]

2:when I add the sources in the job file, I have comfirmed that there is tab instead of 8 blank on the line, still it showed missing separator error.[image]

Comment: According to the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) web site, GCC 3.2.3 was released on 2003-04-23.  That's getting to be antique (and has been for quite a few years).  If you can't upgrade the compiler, downgrade the source code so it will work with the old version of the standard.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, understand and this is what I am trying to do--downgrading. Just that I am no expert on C++, thus I came here for advice/help.

Comment: Please do not update questions with follow up questions. Your issue has been solved by one of the answers. Accept it and ask a new question with your follow up. Otherwise it is hard to follow what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that the function `std::map::at` does not exist in your environment.

This function is introduced in C++11, so your old GCC version does not support it.

Try to replace this function with alternatives, like `std::map::find` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement std::map::at yourself, for exmaple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <map>

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
T2 mapAt(std::map<T1, T2, T3, T4>& m, const T1& key)
{
    typeof(m.begin()) mit = m.find(key);
    if (mit == m.end() || mit->first != key)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("map::at");
    }
    return mit->second;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> mp;
    mp[2] = 3;
    std::cout<<mapAt(mp, 2)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<mapAt(mp, 3)<<std::endl; // will raise an exception
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry I implemented the template incorrectly (this is incorrect for std::string and sorry I don't how to correct it). Here is a degraded version. It restricts type of map but should work on every C++ version.

```
std::string& mapAt(std::map<std::string, std::string>& m, const std::string& key)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator mit = m.find(key);
    if (mit == m.end() || mit->first != key)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("map::at");
    }
    return mit->second;
}
```

Comment: HI, I have put the original part of code which showed up errors. So in order to add implement this std::map::at myself, I just need to copy your T2 part of code and modify the original at to mapAT? Or is there any other necessary work?

Comment: @Jinstrong, you need to `#include <stdexcept>` if you want to simulate how `std::map::at` deals with missing items, or you can just simply return the default value as your code does (under this circumstance `stdexcept` is not necessary). And you need to change `_values.at(key)` to `mapAt(_values, key)`. Remember to copy from `template<typename T1`, the template definition is necessary.

Comment: HI Keyu, I just tried as you suggested, a new error showed up:

Comment: @Jinstrong, sorry comment doesn't support new lines. You could answer your own question with code pasted.

Comment: Hi keyu, just added results as in the original post. Not sure how to start a discussion, maybe that would be more effective.

Comment: @Jinstrong, sorry I do the template wrong. Here is a degraded version only applies to `std::map<std::string, std::string>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114504/discussion-between-jinstrong-and-keyu-gan).

Comment: Hi Keyu, I updated the code and now it reports error of converting 'this->INIReader::_Values' to 'std::map<std::string------'. Seems the type is not always string.

Comment: What's your definition of _values?

Comment: from the header file, _values is a private value, as you can see the source code here.  https://github.com/benhoyt/inih/blob/master/cpp/INIReader.h

Comment: I described it in Chat.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `mapAt` accepts its first argument as non-const reference:

```
T2 mapAt(std::map<T1, T2, T3, T4>& m, const T1& key)
```

yet you try to call it from inside the `const` method `INIReader::Get`, where `_values` are treated as a constant `map`.

It is generally better to declare ref-arguments as `const`s provided you do not have a clear intention to modify them.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I tried suggestions here and still some issues remain. So I put forward an issue on the project's github repo and the writer gave a validated solution. It is to change `_values.at(key)` to `_values.find(key)->second`.

I just checked and confirmed that it works here. You can go to this site (https://github.com/benhoyt/inih/issues/49) for the detailed discussion.

Still, thanks for involvement and discussion here.